# Doctrine ODM: How to select Mongo DB database

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-orm, doctrine, odm, database

I use doctrine ODM to persist and load documents from my Mongo DB. I followed this guide: https://doctrine-mongodb-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html

Following this guide all documents get stored in the database "doctrine" by default. But what if I have my own database? How do I select the database? I couldn't find anything use in the documentation nor google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the Configuration class.

```
$config->setDefaultDB('mydbname');
```

Comment: That works, thanks. Maybe one more question. I have a document with the following id: `"_id": ObjectId("5345a88b22272deec6db2cca")` If I now do `$dm->find('Document', '5345a88b22272deec6db2cca');` I only get null. Isn't it the id?